# Storing Wooden Board Game Components

Tags: storage, components

I generally store my board game components in plastic bags as many do. Today I noticed that some of my games have a hole punched in the bags and it made we wonder if there was a reason for that.

Are there any benefits or issues caused by one storage method over the other? Or is it just to allow the air out making the game pack better.

Comment: I think it is just what the manufacturer wants to use

Answer (score 3):

It allows the air to be removed from the bag so it takes up less space.